# Converting XLSX to JSON with a primary key and arrays?

Tags: json, excel, csv

I have a custom script that takes a JSON input.  The JSON was originally created from an XLSX file by someone other than me.  I was tasked with converting the updated XLSX into the same JSON format.  The issue I'm having is that the JSON format is not 'per row', there are arrays of values.  For example, this table:

```
|  File  | Year | State |
| ------ | -----|------ |
| File1  | 1978 | MA    |
| File1  | 1978 | VT    |
| File1  | 1979 | MA    |
```

Should look like:

```
  {
      "File": "File1",
      "Year": [ "1978","1979" ],
      "State": [ "MA", "VT" ]
}
```

The person who did the conversion originally is no longer with our organization but I have their old laptop and scripts on Gitlab and couldn't find any custom script to do this.

I'm wondering if there is an online tool or option to do this when saving as JSON format in Excel?   I'm just hoping to not have to write a custom script since this was done before, so I'm hoping she just knew of a hack that I don't know about!

Thank you!

Comment: The JSON snippet you posted seems to be the unique values per column. This isn't about per-row formats or not. There's no way to identify what each row contains with such data. What language are you using? There are libraries that can read Excel files. After that, you need to identify the unique values in code and use them to generate a JSON string. If you use Python, you could use `read_excel` to read the file, then `unique` on each column to get the unique values.

Answer (score 1):

If you "save" your XLSX "as" CSV then you can use a tool like [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (available [here](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases) for several OSs) for converting the CSV to JSON:

```bash
mlr --icsv put -q '
    is_null(@m) { @m = apply($*, func(k,v) { return { k: {} }; }); }
    for (k,v in $*) { if (! haskey(@m[k], v)) { @m[k][v] = null; } }
    end { dump(apply(@m, func(k,v) { return {k: get_keys(v)}; })); }
' file.csv
```

###### Example

Given a CSV file whose **raw** content is:

```bash
File,Year,State
"File1","1978","MA"
"File1","1978","VT"
"File1","1979","MA"
```

The output will be:

```json
{
  "File": ["File1"],
  "Year": ["1978", "1979"],
  "State": ["MA", "VT"]
}
```

Comment: Fravadona thank you!  I got miller running and converted the XLSX to CSV but I get the error, "mlr: conditional expression did not evaluate to boolean at DSL expression line 3 column 27."  Does the CSV have to have only 3 cols?  Because I do have other fields.  I don't understand how the function is working to adapt it.

Comment: @xanabobana the code should handle any number of fields. The problem might be some type-inference, as the `v` in `haskey(@m[k], v)` is expected to be a string; try adding the `-S` option to the command: `mlr -S —icsv …`